# How to call onbeforeunload without disconnect websockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

friends! I noticed one thing. When I'm closing browser tab by use onbeforeunload browser is closing a websocket connection. Here code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    return "Close tab?";
}
```

I use socket.io for work with websockets. How to call onbeforeunload without disconnect websockets? Thank you!

Comment: Makes no sense. Try to explain yourself

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce. Have you tried on several browsers/OS'?